Canvas app classic combo box shows looks double
The combo box looks like this (like double) whenever I want to search. The comb box "Allow Multiple selection" is on.
What can I do to resolve this?

This is the treeview of the app, I don't see 2 combo boxes

Thank you

Can you post a capture of the treeview of your app? It seems there are two combo at the same place.

Posted the treeview of the app. I don't see 2 combo boxes

Maybe you can delete it, and add it agin to understand what is going on...

I would click through each of you treeview items to see which one highlights the entire combobox. It looks like the combobox you currently have selected isn't highlighting the entire control
